# Find sibling of root page for current locale in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

My site's menu is created by selecting the root page's children:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_menuitems(context):
    site_root = Site.find_for_request(context["request"]).root_page
    menuitems = site_root.get_children().live().in_menu()
    return menuitems
```

But as the site is available in multiple languages, I need to find the localized sibling of the (English) root page to get a localized menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was *much* simpler than expected:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_menuitems(context):
    site_root = Site.find_for_request(context["request"]).root_page.localized
    menuitems = site_root.get_children().live().in_menu()
    return menuitems
```

Comment: You can also use root_page.get_translations(inclusive=True) to return the set of localized root pages - useful for building the sitemap.